# nodejs version management using wrong version when installing modules

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am using node version management from https://github.com/tj/n

```
$ node --version
v4.2.4
$ npm --version
1.3.1
```

I have removed my node_modules and tried to run `$npm install` but i get warning messages such as

```
npm WARN engine postcss@5.0.13: wanted: {"node":">=0.12"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
```

i have updated my packages.json to include:

```
  "engineStrict" : true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.2.4"
  },
```

any advice much appreciated

what am i missing

Comment: Are you calling `npm install` with `sudo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i needed to open a new terminal window for the settings to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

please use nodejs v12.0
- download : https://nodejs.org/download/release/v0.12.0/node-v0.12.0.tar.gz (extract, make & make install)
After install nodejs v12.0, please retry it.

Answer (score -1):

what tcss wanted node version ">=0.12", your node current version "0.10.25"

try to uninstall your old version, and reinstall node 4.2.4